# JDBC Driver class not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

i have a problem with configuration of hibernate when i run the class test it affich:

```
creating session factory
3 mai 2011 09:47:50 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 2.1.6
3 mai 2011 09:47:50 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
3 mai 2011 09:47:50 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using CGLIB reflection optimizer
3 mai 2011 09:47:50 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from file: hibernate.cfg.xml
3 mai 2011 09:47:51 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Mapping resource: org/domain/projet/config/Employe.hbm.xml
3 mai 2011 09:47:52 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Binder bindRootClass
INFO: Mapping class: org.domain.projet.config.Employe -> employe
3 mai 2011 09:47:52 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: Configured SessionFactory: 
3 mai 2011 09:47:52 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration secondPassCompile
INFO: processing one-to-many association mappings
3 mai 2011 09:47:52 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration secondPassCompile
INFO: processing one-to-one association property references
3 mai 2011 09:47:52 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration secondPassCompile
INFO: processing foreign key constraints
3 mai 2011 09:47:52 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
ATTENTION: No dialect set - using GenericDialect: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
3 mai 2011 09:47:52 net.sf.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: Using dialect: net.sf.hibernate.dialect.GenericDialect
3 mai 2011 09:47:52 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Use outer join fetching: true
3 mai 2011 09:47:52 net.sf.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
3 mai 2011 09:47:52 net.sf.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Hibernate connection pool size: 1
JDBC Driver class not found: com.jdbc.mysql.driver
3 mai 2011 09:47:52 net.sf.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
GRAVE: JDBC Driver class not found: com.jdbc.mysql.driver
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a [mysql-connector-*.jar](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) on your classpath

Comment: but i have the connector for mysql 5.0 but isnt work :( and i put in the hibernate configuration file:  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.jdbc.mysql.driver</property>

Answer (score 0):

Try using these property values:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 ...
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

Check that [hibernate3.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.2.0.cr2/hibernate-3.2.0.cr2.jar) is in your path also.

Comment: thank you i find the error it was net.fr.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect  :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> JDBC Driver class not found: com.jdbc.mysql.driver
> ```

The full qualified class name is case sensitive. You need to declare `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` with uppercase `D` in your Hibernate config file, not `com.mysql.jdbc.driver` with lowercase `d`.